# large csv file not uploaded to database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I having a csv file with 30000 data i am trying to upload all the data to MySQL but it not uploading the data to mysql.

but if try with small data like 100 data it uploading to database .

Can anyone help me how to make it work

Below is my code

my upload.php

```
<?php


include("db.php");
//Upload File

$sql="SELECT MAX(upload_id) FROM contact";
$result=mysqli_query( $MySQLi,$sql);

     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $highest_id = $row[0];
//print $highest_id;

$uploadid = $highest_id+1;

//print $uploadid;

$dropdown = $_POST['DROP'];

print $dropdown;


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


       //Import uploaded file to Database

        $file = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']; 

        $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    for ($lines = 0; $data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",",'"'); $lines++) {
        if ($lines == 0) continue;
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 32; $i ++)
        {
            if (!isset($data[$i]))
                $data[$i] = ''; 
        }

                $import="INSERT into contact
                  (name, contacttype, nationality, mobile1, country1,`mobile2`,`country2`,
                  email1,`email2`, phone, fax,`country3`, twon, area, restatus, retype, 
                  reproject1, contactgroup, freezone1, gender, 
                  dateofbirth, married, children, educationlevel, jobrole, 
                  jobsector, driverslicense, language,media, media2, media3, media4, age, 
                  salary, created, upload, image, companyname, 
                  businesscategory, subcategory, upload_id)
                  values('$data[0]', '$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]',
                         '$data[4]', '$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]',
                         '$data[8]','$data[9]','$data[10]','$data[11]',
                         '$data[12]','$data[13]','$data[14]','$data[15]',
                         '$data[16]','$data[17]','$data[18]','$data[19]',
                         '$data[20]','$data[21]','$data[22]','$data[23]',
                         '$data[24]','$data[25]','$data[26]','$data[27]','$data[28]','$data[29]','$data[30]',
                         '$data[31]','$data[32]','$data[33]',".time().",'$data[35]','$data[36]','$data[37]', '$data[38]','$data[39]','$data[17]') ";
                print $import;
                mysqli_query( $MySQLi,$import) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $sql - Error: ".mysqli_error(), E_USER_ERROR);


            //view upload form
}
fclose($handle);
print "Import done";


//header("Location: /uploadanddelete.php");

}else {

print "Import Failed";

}

?>
```

my uploaddata.php

```
<p>Upload new csv by browsing to file and clicking on Upload </p>

<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action="upload.php" method="post" class='form-horizontal form-column form-bordered'>

<p>File name to import: 

<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br /><br /> </p>

                                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>

</form>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and are simply assuming your csv upload can never fail. There's a `['error']` parameter in $_FILES for a reason... check it.

Comment: @marc it doesnt showing any error

Answer (score 1):

It looks ok so there can be this problems:

**Is file uploaded?**

**NO:** check upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini

**Is imported some lines or it no import any line when you have big file?**

**NO:** Check you memory_limit (php.ini) you can increase it by this:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
```

**YES:** Check your max_execution_time (php.ini) you can increase it by this:

```
set_time_limit ($seconds)
```

If it doesn't help try to debug in which part of your code is dyinig

Answer (score 0):

isset is not the most reliable check.  strlen is a better test.

`settype` would be a simple way to handle it without and `if`

Because there is no error does not mean the record got inserted.  You must check the `rows_affected`.  You really do not need to check the error, only the rows_affected.  If there is an error no rows will be affected.

Keeping a count of rows inserted and errors would eliminate the the need to check for file upload errors (as does your print $sql).

Replace:

```
if (!isset($data[$i]))
                $data[$i] = '';
```

With:

```
settype($data[$i],'string');
```

OR

```
 if (strlen($data[$i]) < 1){$data[$i] = ''};
```

Change:

```
print $import;
mysqli_query( $MySQLi,$import) 
or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $sql - Error: ".mysqli_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
```

To:

```
mysqli_query( $MySQLi,$import);
if (mysqli_affected_rows($MySQLi) !=1 || mysqli_errno($MySQLi) > 0)){
  echo '<p class="warn">' . mysqli_error($MySQLi) . "<br/>$import</p>";
  $errors++;
}
else{
  $imported++;
  echo "<p>$import</p>";
}
```

Then end it with the results:

```
echo "<p>$imported Records Imported with $errors Errors</p>";
```

**CSS**

```
.warn{color:#f00;}
p{padding:0;margin:.1em;}
body{background:#000;color:#ff0;font-size:.8em;}
```

Comment: i am trying to print the sql query even its nit printing

Comment: Added an echo by `$imported++`